# unable to fetch the value of database column using user_id and text_id in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Hi in the below erb code I want to fetch the value of a column `counter` present in favorite table using current_user.id and the text_id. The relationship of the models are as below.

I am new to rails and I am not sure if we can fetch the value in the view. Please help.

```
<p>
  All Favorites
    <% if ***current_user.favorite.counter == ?*** %>
      <%= link_to #do something %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to #do something else %>
    <% end %>
</p>
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_texts, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Text'
```

Favorite.rb

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
```

Favorite table has the following database columns

```
id | text_id | favorited_type | user_id |  created_at |  updated_at | counter
```

Also the text_id is unique for the user_id.

The user controller has the following code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @texts = current_user.favorite_texts
    @favorite_groups = @user.favorite_groups
    @fav_group = FavoriteGroup.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand your request, but this code: `current_user.favorites.where(favorited_type: 'Text', favorited_id: text_id).first.counter` should retrieve the `counter` value of the Favorite record linking a user and a Text

Comment: Yes I want to fetch the `counter` value fetched using the text_id and the user_id.

Comment: @MrYoshiji When I follow the way suggested by you in the controller and save the data fetched by `where` clause in a variable and try to access the `counter` I am getting `undefined method `counter' for nil:NilClass`. I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Counting records

If you want to get the count of an association you would simply do:

```
current_user.favorites.count
```

Which issues a SQL `COUNT(*)` query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."user_id" = ? [["user_id", 1]]
```

However this can be problematic if you are iterating through a large number of records as it will cause what is called a `n+1` issue.

```
users.all do |u|
  if u.favorites.count.zero? # will cause a SQL query for each iteration!
  end
end
```

[`ActiveRecord::Relation#size`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-size) on the other is smart and counts the records in memory if they have been loaded already.

```
def size
  loaded? ? @records.length : count(:all)
end
```

So you would use it together with `.includes` to avoid the n+1 issue.

```
users.all do |u|
  if u.favorites.size.zero?
  end
end
```

## Counter caches

If you want to avoid loading the associated records and at the same time avoid n+1 COUNT queries you can add a counter cache to the owning model.

In this example if you would add a `favorites_count` column to users, and set the option on favorites. Adding a counter to the join model makes very little sense.

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
  # note that counter_cache needs to be set on the belongs_to side
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
end
```

Every time you insert or destroy a Favorite rails will now update the associated user. However there is a slight cost related with the UPDATE query.

One catch is that any existing User will not have the counter cache so you need to iterate through them and reset the cache:

```
User.find_each { |u| User.reset_counters(u.id, :favorites) }
```

Comment: There is a third method which involves using a custom `SELECT` statement which fetches a count of the association while fetching the records. However you might want to wait a bit with that one.

Comment: I was looking to get the value of a column inside the favorites table. Anyways thanks for the information and help. I have tried hit and trial and got the solution to my query at last, will post as answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the counter column in the view (i.e. html.erb ) we have to use the following

```
<p>
  All Favorites
    <% if current_user.favorite_texts.where(id: text.id).pluck(:counter).first == 1 %>
      <%= link_to #do something %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to #do something else %>
    <% end %>
</p>
```

`pluck` returns an array. So I use `.first` to it as my query will always have one value because of the constraint in the favorites table. That is text.id is unique for each user.id.

So the above returns the value of the counter column in the view. Thanks.